# Create a report log and manipulate it in a single script (Debian)

Tags: bash, shell, debian

I would like to create a script, which will create a report file when launched. The name of the file would be something like 
Report-YEAR-MONTH-DATE.log
And the content would include the output of these commands :

```
service apache2 status
df -k 
awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

The problem is that i want to, in the same script, create a file and store things in it.
Here is what i already did :

```
filename = date +"Report-%Y-%M-%D"
service apache2 status > $filename
```

It tells me that the redirection is ambigous, and i saw stuff with _END at the end of the $filename, and i can't find how to resolve it.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: I've got big doubts about `filename = date +"Report-%Y-%M-%D"`. Did you print `$filename` before trying to create a file with that name? And are the `<br>` a typo in your first snippet? if you put that in your script you'll have problems...

Comment: Yes, if i print $filename it works fine, and sorry for the <br>, i deleted them, it's a mistake

Comment: okay but what does it print?

Comment: don't put spaces around "="

Comment: It simply prints Report-2016-11-25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/your/path/"
filename="${path}Report-"$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
service apache2 status > "${filename}"
df -k >> "${filename}"
awk -F ':' '{print $1}' /etc/passwd >> "${filename}"
```

Of course you must change path var to put your directory. Must finish with "/" in this way.

Comment: Working, thank you very much, that was the ${} part which was missing :)